# Welcher Kasus ist in dem folgenden Satz richtig? Dativ oder Genitiv?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, dative

Im geschriebenen Deutsch nimmt die Präposition *wegen* den Genitiv.

Welche Sätze sind korrekt?

> Der Patient kommt zu uns wegen seit ein**er** Woche bestehend**en** rezidivierend**en** bohrend**en** Rückenschmerzen.

> ...wegen seit ein**er** Woche bestehend**er** rezidivierend**er** bohrend**er** Rückenschmerzen.

> ...wegen seit ein**er** Woche bestehend**em** bohrend**em** Rückenschmerz

oder

> ...wegen seit ein**er** Woche bestehend**en** bohrend**en** Rückenschmerz**es**

Sind die Endungen der Adjektiven *bestehend, bohrend, rezidivierend* im Dativ (*seit* nimmt Dativ) oder im Genitiv (*wegen* nimmt Genitiv)?

Auch gilt das für das folgende Beispiel:

> Der Patient klagt über seit ein**er** Woche (Dat.) bestehend**en** (Akk.) trocken**en** (Akk.) Husten.

Ich denke, die Präposition *seit* gibt nur dem Wort *einer Woche* die Dativendung und nicht die Adjektive *bestend, rezidivierend,..* die von der Präposition *wegen* abhängen. Ich denke auch, dass *seit einer Woche* eine separate Präpositionalphrase ist, die nichts zu tun mit dem Kasus der anderen Adjektive hat (,die von anderen Präpositionen *wegen bzw. über* abhängen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alle Sätze sind richtig gebildet (wenn man von der *wegen*-Frage absieht), und meiner Meinung nach auch völlig akzeptabel.  *Wegen* + Dativ ist schon so häufig, dass mir bei einer recht komplexen Aneinanderreihung wie hier der Unterschied gar nicht auffällt, wenn ich nicht bewusst darüber nachdenke.

Die Genitiv-Variante liegt natürlich "auf der sicheren Seite", wenn man puristischen Kommentaren vorbeugen möchte, und wirkt bei einem so elaborierten Kontext auch nicht fehl am Platz. (Die letzte der vier Varianten, mit Singular + Genitiv, wirkt vielleicht am ehesten ein bisschen gesteltzt, aber wieder: in dem Kontext klingt auch das völlig OK).

Auch, dass *seit einer Woche* von Rest unabhängig ist, und die Dativ/Genitiv-Frage nur von *wegen* abhängt, ist völlig richtig; die Phrase fungiert allerdings als Adverbial, welches *bestehen* modifiziert (und das Ganze wird dann nominalisiert).  Vergleiche:

> Der Patient kommt zu uns wegen lebenslang bestehender bohrender Rückenschmerzen.

Side note: man kann Beistriche einfügen, um das Ganze etwas leserlicher zu machen:

> Der Patient kommt zu uns wegen seit einer Woche bestehenden, rezidivierenden und bohrenden Rückenschmerzen.

Dann sieht man auch die Funktion der *seit*-Phrase besser:

> Der Patient kommt zu uns wegen rezidivierenden, seit einer Woche bestehenden und bohrenden Rückenschmerzen.

(Ich würde hier sogar zum Oxford-Komma nach *und* tendieren, aber nur weil ich zu viel Englisch arbeite.  Offiziell vorgesehen wäre es, glaube ich, nicht.)

Comment: Sie haben Recht! Ich weiß, wegen+ Dativ ist auch völlig akzeptabel im geschriebenen Deutsch. Leider gilt nur die Variante wegen+ Genitiv in manchen Sprachprüfungen als richtig, deswegen würde ich auf der sicheren Seite bleiben.

Comment: @Abdullah You could always justify yourself by quoting from official language tests (with the original source in this case apparently being a federal ministry): *wegen Behandlungs- und Aufklärungsfehler**n*** ([source](https://www.telc.net/fileadmin/user_upload/uebungstest_medizin.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

vorab: Ja, die angegebene Zeitspanne ist im Dativ.

> seit eine**r** Woche = Dativ, vgl.:
> seit eine**m** Monat

---

nun zur **Aufzählung der Beschwerden**:

Ja, nach wie vor ist es üblich, nach "wegen" den Genitiv einzusetzen. 
*(Im Zuge des Sprachwandels setzt sich jedoch insbesondere in der gesprochenen Sprache auch nach "wegen" immer häufiger der Dativ durch; vgl. "wegen Urlaub/Umbau geschlossen" statt "wegen Urlaubs/Umbaus geschlossen" - und gilt zumindest in solchen Verbindungen nicht mehr als gänzlich falsch, sondern als zulässig.)*

Doch zurück zur Beantwortung der Frage:
Wenn ein Artikel/Begleiter oder eine Endung eines Adjektivs/Partizips bereits im erweiterten Satzglied vorkommt (die in diesem Beispiel auf den Genitiv verweist --> "bestehend**er**"), erhalten alle nachstehenden Adjektive/Partizipien, die in Abhängigkeit zum gebeugten Adjektiv/Partizip stehen, eine schwache Beugung --> bohrend**en**. Weiters enthält die Beschreibung eine Aufzählung, weshalb ich zusätzlich ein (bzw. mehrere) Komma(s) einsetze - man könnte auch "und" anstelle eines Kommas anwenden.

d.h. meines Erachtens grammatisch richtig (aber aus medizinischer Sicht vermutlich/vielleicht inhaltlich nicht):

> wegen ... bestehend**er** rezidivierend**en,** bohrend**en** Rückenschmerzen 
> wegen ... bestehend**er** rezidivierend**en und** bohrend**en** Rückenschmerzen

*--> "bestehender" bezieht sich auf "rezidivierenden und bohrenden"*

oder: wenn medizinisch betrachtet "bestehend" und "rezidivierend" eigentlich nahezu das Gleiche bedeuten bzw. "rezidivierend" das Partizip "bestehend" genauer definieren soll:

> wegen ... bestehend**er,** rezidivierend**er** bohrenden Rückenschmerzen
> wegen ... bestehend**er und** rezidivierend**er** bohrend**en** Rückenschmerzen
> *--> ev. wiederum klarer, wenn man statt des Kommas "und" einsetzt.

oder einfach den Artikel im Genitiv zusätzlich einfügen:

> wegen **der** ... bestehend**en,** rezidivierend**en** (,) bohrend**en** Rückenschmerzen

---

ad

> "Der Patient klagt über seit einer Woche (Dat.) bestehenden (Akk.) trockenen (Akk.) Husten."

Grammatisch ist der Satz m.E. nicht falsch. Die auf den Akkusativ hinweisende Endung **-en** beim Partizip "bestehend" mit der schwachen Beugung lautet gleich, was den Satz *falsch klingen* lässt, und mein Sprachgefühl verlangt an dieser Stelle nach einem zusätzlichen Artikel - dieser ist hier aber aus grammatischer Sicht optional.

**Änderungsvorschlag**:

> ... klagt über **den** seit einer Woche bestehend**en** trocken**en** Husten.

Comment: _Klagt seit einer Woche über den bestehenden Husten_ und _klagt über den seit einer Woche bestehenden Husten_ bedeuten aber schon ganz verschiedene Sachverhalte!

Comment: @phipsgabler: Stimmt! ... hab's eben richtig gestellt. Danke für den Hinweis! :-)